# ROS Answers SE migration: rosbag record

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to record all the topics on ros with rosbag, but there are some topics that I don't want, for exemple /cmd_vel and all the topics releted to the camera /camera/*.

I have tried with rosbag record -a -x "/cmd_vel" -x "/camera(.*)" and it doesn't work, but if i try it separatley it does work and it donsen't record /cmd_vel or /camera* is there some command to exclude from the record more than one topic or types of topics?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12269/rosbag-record/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2011-12-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How about this:

- rosbag record -a -x "((/cmd_vel)|(/camera(.*)))"

You can logically control the topics to exclude, using & or |, as you would in python

---

Originally posted by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) with karma: 682 on 2011-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-12-08**:
Give or take the fact that getting regular expressions written down correctly (in shell, at that) can be a pain. I'd suggest a few minutes with xargs.